# Sum of two Entry widgets in tkinter without buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't figure this out. I want to sum two entries and then put the sum in a label, without any buttons. 
In my first example, I only got one entry and that works perfectly and it updates the label when typing.

In my first example I got two entries and I'm trying to pass both into the label (doesn't work).

In my third example, I'll tried to put the result in a list and them sum it and then trying to pass the result to the label, and that dosent work either.

I don't understand how I can pass one entry to the label, but I can't do it with two entries added together!

What to do??

Example one (one entry):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
var.set(float(0.000))

t1 = Entry(root, textvariable = var)
t1.pack()


l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Example two (two entries):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var1 = DoubleVar()
var1.set(float(0.100))
var2 = DoubleVar()
var2.set(float(0.200))


t1 = Entry(root, textvariable = var1)
t1.pack()
t2 = Entry(root, textvariable = var2)
t2.pack()

result = var1 + var2

l = Label(root, textvariable = result)
l.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Example tree (two entries, with list): I get this error,

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'DoubleVar'
> ```

How does I handle this??

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var1 = DoubleVar()
var1.set(float(0.100))
var2 = DoubleVar()
var2.set(float(0.200))

t1 = Entry(root, textvariable = var1)
t1.pack()
t2 = Entry(root, textvariable = var2)
t2.pack()

resultList = [var1, var2]
resultSum = sum(resultList)

l = Label(root, textvariable = resultSum)
l.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value from a Tkinter Variable you need to use its `.get` method. And you can use Tkinter's [trace](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) mechanism to watch the variables associated with your Entry widgets. Whenever the Entry values change the Label will automatically update.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.DoubleVar()
t1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var1)
t1.pack()

var2 = tk.DoubleVar()
t2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2)
t2.pack()

result = tk.DoubleVar()
l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=result)
l.pack()

# Put trace callbacks on the Entry DoubleVars
def set_label(name, index, mode):
    result.set(var1.get() + var2.get())

var1.trace('w', set_label)
var2.trace('w', set_label)

# Setting the vars will trigger the trace
var1.set(0.25)
var2.set(0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Math No worries! And thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke .get() to get the values of your DoubleVars. I don’t have access to tkinter at the moment (using Pythonista) to test this, but you should be able to do something like:

```
resultList = [var1.get(), var2.get()]
resultSum = sum(resultList)
```

Comment: Thanks @Superspork  Yes, I can now get and print the sum to the console, but not pass it to the label.

Comment: I believe you can only pass a value to a widget using a tkinter var. try declaring resultSum as a DoubleVar and then .set() the result to it.